# Get Dynamic Select option in Clone Node using Javscript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, forms

I'm trying to create a form where I'm giving **dynamic** select option i.e one select option will depend on another select option, as you can see in the **Image** below, if Gender is **male** and Child the age group is between **1-18** similarly for Adult its greater than 18.

And By clicking `Add member` I'm cloning the whole `Person div`, but the script is not working for the cloned node and I'm only getting `AgeGroup` of the 1st div whose clone is created.

I'm trying to build this form in Django if that helps.

My code:

```
## html code

          <button class="btn" id="addMember">Add Member</button>

          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <label>Optimise for:</label>
                       <div class="input-group mb-3">
                           <select class="custom-select" id="type" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
                                        <option value="Child">Child</option> 
                                        <option value="Adult">Adult</option> 
                            </select>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label>Gender: </label>
                          <div class="input-group mb-3">
                           <select name="h_gender" class="custom-select" id="gender" required>
                                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
                                        <option value="Male">Male</option> 
                                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                 <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                      <label>Age Group:</label>
                         <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <div id="selectList">
                            </div>
                          </div>
                 </div>


        document.getElementById('addMember').onclick = function() {
            var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
            var clonedNode = addOnDiv.querySelector('.memberBody').cloneNode(true);
            addOnDiv.appendChild( clonedNode );
        }

 ## for select
        
        $("select").change(function() {
            var selectedVal = $('#type').val();
            var selectedGender = $('#gender').val();
            console.log(selectedGender);   
            console.log(selectedVal);
            
            if('Child' === selectedVal){
                var childGroup = '<select name="h_ageGroup" class="custom-select"> <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>........</select>';
                $('#selectList').html(childGroup);
            }
            if('Adult' === selectedVal ){
                var childGroup = '<select name="h_ageGroup" class="custom-select"> <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option> <option value=">18 Years"> >18 Years </option></select>';
                $('#selectList').html(childGroup);
            }

    });
```

**How can I get dynamic select on my cloned node too.** Is there any other way through which I can achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Hi, show html code as well .

Comment: Hey, I have added HTML code aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your html are dynamcially created you need to bind it to some static element i.e : any div , document ..etc . Then , in your code you have use same ids for mutliple elements instead use `class` selector and then get required values using `$(this).closest('.memberBody')` this will get closest div from select and then use `.find` to get required values

***Demo Code*** :

```js
document.getElementById('addMember').onclick = function() {
  var addOnDiv = document.getElementById('addon');
  var clonedNode = addOnDiv.querySelector('.memberBody').cloneNode(true);
  $(clonedNode).find('.selectList').html('') //empty age group div
  addOnDiv.appendChild(clonedNode);
}
//just specify select when this event should get called..
$(document).on('change', '.type , .gender', function() {
  //use closest and find to get only value where slect has been change
  var selectedVal = $(this).closest('.memberBody').find('.type').val();
  var selectedGender = $(this).closest('.memberBody').find('.gender').val();

  if ('Child' === selectedVal) {
    var childGroup = '<select name="h_ageGroup" class="custom-select"> <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>........</select>';
    $(this).closest('.memberBody').find('.selectList').html(childGroup);
  }
  if ('Adult' === selectedVal) {
    var childGroup = '<select name="h_ageGroup" class="custom-select"> <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option> <option value=">18 Years"> >18 Years </option></select>';
    $(this).closest('.memberBody').find('.selectList').html(childGroup);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="addMember">Add Member</button>
<div id="addon">
  <div class="memberBody">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Optimise for:</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <!--aded class-->
        <select class="custom-select type" required>
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
          <option value="Child">Child</option>
          <option value="Adult">Adult</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Gender: </label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <!--aded class-->
        <select name="h_gender" class="custom-select gender" required>
          <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
          <option value="Male">Male</option>
          <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label>Age Group:</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <!--aded class-->
        <div class="selectList">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I'm selecting `Adult` and `Male` and when I choose `> 18` it's not showing inside select.

Comment: *it's not showing inside select..* ? please can you elaborate more ?

Comment: try selecting `> 18`

Comment: Did you get the issue ?

Comment: yes .. is that issue was there before as well ?

Comment: No, For the First Person Every thing was working perfectly Fine

Comment: ok i will look into that then will update you because i am not seeing anything wrong here

Comment: sure! I'll let you know if I get any solution too

Comment: Hi i got what's wrong here :P the change event is calling even for age select-box that why its just replacing html again and again .Updated code .

Comment: Right! Got It Thanks